# Display multiple row into one single row in SQL/Oracle (not comma separated)

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a SQL code for below scenario

I have a table like below

```
Id  Comments    Type
1   Work    Day
1   Play    Afternoon
1   Sleep   Night
```

The data needs to be merged in one single

```
Id  Comments    Type
1    Work       Day
     Play       Afternoon
     Sleep      Night
```

One data below another data

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) = 1 THEN Id ELSE Null END As Id,
    Comments, Type
FROM
    yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine on Oracle 11+. What I did is aggregated Comments and Type column and in between, I inserted CHR(10), which is the ASCII value of newline. You might not see the output correctly in your client, but if you run it in sql developer command line you would see the output at desired.

```
          WITH TBL (ID,COMMENTS,TYPE)
          AS (
          SELECT 1,'Work','Day' FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 1,'Play','Afternoon' FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 1,'Sleep','Night' FROM DUAL 
          )
          SELECT ID, 
          LISTAGG(COMMENTS,CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID)  COMMENTS,
           LISTAGG(TYPE,CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID)  TYPE
          from tbl group by id
```